# NSUserDefaults boolforKey limitation by design?

Tags: cocoa-touch, foundation

The `NSUserDefaults` API documentation has the `boolForKey:` message which is described like this -

```
boolForKey:
```

Returns the Boolean value associated with the specified key.

```
- (BOOL)boolForKey:(NSString *)defaultName
```

Return Value
If a boolean value is associated with defaultName in the user defaults, that value is returned. Otherwise, NO is returned.

Given that a `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"some_Key"]` gives back a NO it can be either because the key does not exist or the key exists and has a `boolean` value NO. How can we differentiate? As of now, I can only avoid getting into this situation in the first place.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1965765/iphone-dev-nsuserdefaults-check-for-boolean-existance . I so DID NOT find this one when i searched before. :)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You are using the user defaults incorrectly. At the launch of your app, you are supposed to call `-[NSUserDefaults registerDefaults:]` with a dictionary that contains the default values for all preferences.

Then, if the user has not set a preference, `-boolForKey` will return the default value.

Comment: I wouldn’t go so far and say that he uses the user defaults incorrectly. Registering defaults is optional and in his situation probably more convenient, but Mike Abdullah’s answer just fits better.

Answer (score 29):

Use the `-objectForKey:` method as well. This will tell you whether the key exists.

Comment: BOOLs are not objects, so this cannot be used.

Comment: Yes `BOOL`s are not objects, but `NSUserDefaults` handles them as `NSNumber` instances, which is what you'll get from `-objectForKey:`